# Binary operator '*' cannot be applied to operands of type 'CGRect' and 'CGFloat'

Tags: swift

I got a problem with binary operator,

which is

```
scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height+(self.view.frame* (1/10) *CGFloat(UIImage.count)))
```

has problem `CGRect` and `Int`.

I thought problem was the `1/10`, so I replaced that with `CGFloat(1/10)`:

```
scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height+(self.view.frame* *CGFloat(UIImage.count)))
```

But now, I got new message type `CGRect` and `CGFloat`

How can I get rid of this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have stayed with `1 / 10`, avoiding the cast. Changing that to `CGFloat(1/10)` actually introduces another problem, telling the compiler “hey, even though this is `CGFloat` parameter, I really want you to do integer math of `1` divided by `10` (which is zero!) and then cast that to a `CGFloat`.”

So, you can stick with `1 / 10` and because that parameter is `CGFloat`, it will correctly do the right floating point math. The real problem is simply that you were multiplying the `view.frame` times `1 / 10`, rather than the `view.frame.height`:

```
scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: view.frame.width,
                                height: view.frame.height + (view.frame.height * 1 / 10 * CGFloat(UIImage.count)))
```

I don’t know what to make of that `UIImage.count` reference, so I’ve left that as is, but that’s obviously not right.

---

While the above works perfectly, but most of us, coming from other languages would explicitly specify the numbers as floating point numbers, say `... * 1.0 / 10.0` or just `... * 0.1` or whatever, to make it completely unambiguous that we don’t want it doing any integer math:

```
scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: view.frame.width,
                                height: view.frame.height + (view.frame.height / 10.0 * CGFloat(UIImage.count)))
```

This is, in this particular example, completely equivalent to what is above, but the use of `10.0` rather than `10` makes it absolutely clear that we want to do floating point math.

Answer (score 0):

You **can't** multiply `self.view.frame : CGRect` with `CGFloat(1/10) : CGFloat`.

You probably forgot to pick `width` or `height` on that `self.view.frame` command. As soon as you do that, you will be dealing with `CGFloat` and `CGFloat` and that will get rid of the error.

Replace:

```
CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height + (self.view.frame * CGFloat(1/10) * CGFloat(UIImage.count)))
```

with:

```
CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height + (self.view.frame.<#width or height#> * CGFloat(1/10) * CGFloat(UIImage.count)))
```

and specify if you want `width` or `height`.

**Notes**: 
`UIImage` doesn't have an attribute named `count`.

As @Rob mentioned, `CGfloat(1/10)` is `0.0`, therefore that parenthesis operation will always result in `0` since you're multiplying with `0`.

Comment: `CGFloat(1/10)` is `0.0`. Get rid of the `CGFloat` cast and just say `1 / 10` or `0.1` and, because that parameter is `CGFloat`, you’ll bypass the integer math altogether.

Comment: I change it because I got error before. But now it doesn't matter!

Answer (score 0):

`self.view.frame` is CGRect and `CGFloat(1/10)` is CGFloat, so you cannot make direct operator `*` between them. Also as Rob said in the comment, CGFloat(1/10) is 0.0, so you should use 0.1.

To fix it, use this line:

```
scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height+(self.view.frame.size.height * 0.1 * CGFloat(UIImage.count)))
```

Hope this helps.